# Handle a json string having a null value in one of the fields in scala

Tags: java, json, scala

I am trying to parse a json string with one of the fields as null.While parsing it I am getting a Null pointer exception.Below is a snippet of code.

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
val someJsonString = """{"foo":2,"bar":2}"""
JSON.parseRaw(someJsonString)  //res0: Option[scala.util.parsing.json.JSONType] = Some({"foo" : 2.0, "bar" : 2.0})

val someJsonStringWithNull = """{"foo":null,"bar":2}"""
JSON.parseRaw(someJsonStringWithNull) //getting null pointer exception java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How will I able to parse the second string i.e. someJsonStringWithNull succesfully?Do i need to use any other library?

Comment: You haven't said which JSON library you are using, but if it build-in JSON parser, I would suggest anything else.

Comment: I am using import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON library

Comment: Try [dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit) FTW! [It handles `null` as `None` values](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon/blob/02335510d1d7202a4cfcc431d12d2c1c979b0e65/src/test/scala/com/github/pathikrit/dijon/DijonSpec.scala#L238-L250).

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON` is way deprecated